# AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock in jupyter notebook

Tags: time, attributes, jupyter

in juppyter notebook getting error as

AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
t0=time.clock() # start timer for finding simulation time

AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
**for following code**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
t0=time.clock() # start timer for finding simulation time

# Problem parameters
k1=50 # cart 1 spring constant (N/m)
k2=50 # cart 2 spring constant (N/m)
b1=3 # cart 1 viscous damping coefficient (kg/s)
b2=3 # cart 2 viscous damping coefficient (kg/s)
m1=5 # cart 1 mass (kg)
m2=5 # cart 2 mass (kg)
x10=1 # cart 1 initial position (m)
x20=-1 # cart 2 initial position (m)
v10=0 # cart 1 initial velocity (m/s)
v20=0 # cart 2 initial velocity (m/s)

# Set time step stuff
simTime=10 # simulation time (s)
tStep=0.001 # simulation time step
iterations=int(simTime/tStep) # total number of iterations
t=np.arange(0,iterations)

# Pre-allocate variables for speed and add initial conditions
x1=np.zeros((iterations,1))
x1[0,:]=x10
x2=np.zeros((iterations,1))
x2[0,:]=x20
v1=np.zeros((iterations,1))
v1[0,:]=v10
v2=np.zeros((iterations,1))
v2[0,:]=v20
a1=np.zeros((iterations,1))
a1[0,:]=-(b1*v10-b2*(v20-v10)+k1*x10-k2*(x20-x10))/m1
a2=np.zeros((iterations,1))
a2[0,:]=-(b2*(v20-v10)+k2*(x20-x10))/m2

# Solve the ODE's with Euler's Method
for n in range(1,iterations):
  x1[n,:]=x1[n-1,:]+v1[n-1,:]*tStep # cart 1 position
  x2[n,:]=x2[n-1,:]+v2[n-1,:]*tStep # cart 2 position
  v1[n,:]=v1[n-1,:]+a1[n-1,:]*tStep # cart 1 velocity
  v2[n,:]=v2[n-1,:]+a2[n-1,:]*tStep # cart 2 velocity
  # Find cart accelerations
  a1[n,:]=-(b1*v1[n,:]-b2*(v2[n,:]-v1[n,:])+k1*x1[n,:]-k2*(x2[n,:]-x1[n,:]))/m1
  a2[n,:]=-(b2*(v2[n,:]-v1[n,:])+k2*(x2[n,:]-x1[n,:]))/m2
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Python version >3.7? The `time.clock` function has been removed as of version Python 3.8. The removal notice was included in the [time documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html) for Python 3.7.