# how to install time function in jupyter notebook

Tags: numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have a program importing NumPy, time in jupyter notebook, I had install NumPy but do I need to install time as well? if yes then how to? will pip install time work in command propmt?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67146974/13618895                                                    view this query for detali

Comment: `time` is part of the Python standard library, so it should already be installed and imported.